# Hall sensor for slowly varying magnetic fields

Tags: amplifier, sensor, noise, frequency

I am trying to measure the change in the field of a permanent magnet (at about 50 mT) due to temperature fluctuations at room temperature (timescale ~ mins to hours). The sensor I am currently using is a A1326 linear hall effect sensor from Allegro (https://www.digikey.ch/de/datasheets/allegromicrosystemsllc/allegro-microsystems-llca132456datasheetashx). The sensor has an output of 2.5 V DC and varies between 0 V and 5 V. Currently I am limited by low frequency (1/f) noise coming from the Hall sensor. This is where my two questions come in:

1. Does this noise generally come from the Hall element itself or from the electronics (presumably amplifiers) present within the Hall sensor?
2. Would chopper-stabilization of the amplifier in the Hall sensor mitigate the 1/f noise? Such as found in this sensor from TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5053.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Would chopper-stabilization of the amplifier in the Hall sensor
>   mitigate the 1/f noise?

No, because the sensor internally has a chopper amplifier: -

> Chopper stabilization is a unique approach  used to minimize Hall
>   offset on the chip. Allegro employs a  technique to remove key sources
>   of the output drift induced by  thermal and mechanical stresses

[image]

> Does this noise generally come from the Hall element itself or from
>   the electronics (presumably amplifiers) present within the Hall
>   sensor?

Now that's a good question and I don't think anyone can tell from reading the data sheet but I'm sure if you low-pass filtered the signal you would remove a lot of noise.

For instance, the spec says the noise is 1.3 mG / \$\sqrt{Hz}\$ and this means that the noise produced over a 1000 Hz bandwidth is 1.3 mG x 31.62 = about 41 milli gauss and given that 1 gauss is one ten-thousandth of a tesla, the noise is equivalent to a magnetic noise of 4.1 uT i.e. not very much compared to your measurement range of 50 mT.

Of course, if you are looking at this noise on an o-scope with 50 MHz bandwidth, it will look like equivalent to about 1 mT but you don't need the bandwidth so just slug the output with a simple RC filter of a few hundred Hz cut-off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to measure slow (sub)uT variations at 50 mT. I have tried low pass RC filters with up to 0.01 Hz cut-off, after which the low frequency noise limits the resolution. The problem is that this low f noise is at least 100 uVpp or 4 uT, i.e. much larger than the specs. We use very precise and stable batteries as a source that show no low frequency fluctuations. Every other source (diff amp after Hall, A-D converter) has been ruled out. Hence it is unclear where the low frequency noise comes from let alone how to mitigate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: A 1 Hz filter would give about 0.2 uT noise and if you are still seeing noise of about 4 uT with a 0.01 Hz filter either you have implemented the filter incorrectly, your measurement amplification chain is too noisy, or the device's data sheet is phoney. Explain more about your diff amp by posting the circuit as an addendum to your question.